can't inject(?) spring @Service bean into jsf @Named managed bean via SpringBeanAutowiringSupport and @Autowired
spring and jsf both work on their own without any issues so I'm only including code which is relevant for the spring-jsf connection.
managed bean:
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ZManagedBean extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println(getzService());
    }

    @Autowired
    ZService zService;

    public ZService getzService() {return zService;}
    public void setzService(ZService zService) {this.zService = zService;}


    public void register() {
        System.out.println("jsf alone works");
        zService.checkInjection();
    }

} 

its deploying successfully but gives an error when calling register().
important logs:
[INFO] [] [jakarta.enterprise.logging.stdout] [tid: _ThreadID=73 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [levelValue: 800] [[
  org.demoNoBoot2.zdemo.ZService@2816d266]]

first time initializing the managed bean, the service is injected successfully within the PostConstruct, but calling register() gives nullptrexc
[FATAL] [faces.context.exception.handler.log] [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.context] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [levelValue: 1100] [[
  Cannot invoke "org.demoNoBoot2.zdemo.ZService.checkInjection()" because "this.zService" is null]]

as the managed bean gets instantiated again (ViewScoped), injection fails (also in PostConstruct).
Making the managed bean @ApplicationScoped doesn't fix the problem (it still prints the zService address in the logs and also prints it again later (I think when I first call the page) but this time with zService address null)

I doubt @Autowired actually works. Ditch the SpringBeanAutowiringSupport and configure/setup the SpringBeanFacesELResolver and WebApplicationContextFacesELResolver. Then replace @Autowired with either @Inject or use @ManagedResource with the proper beanname. This will let JSF do a proper lookup in Spring.

I made a faces-config.xml and put the Resolvers in it. Replaces @Autowired with @Inject but still does not work. I think you ment @ManagedProperty("#{zService}") instead of ManagedResource. I still tried both (@ManagedResource  was a class annotation) but nothing worked. Could you maybe wirte a answer with code examples you ment if i got something wrong? I also could open up another question showing my faces-config.xml and other classes/ xml`s @M. Deinum

JSF is a long time ago for me (me and JSF aren't friends ;) ). That being said it should indeed be @ManagedProperty not sure why that didn't work as I would expect it either to hard fail or work but not silenty fail. Which JSF and Spring versions are you using?

I am using spring-webmvc 6.1.13 and jakarta.jakartaee-web-api 9.1.0 (faces 3.0). also using glassfish7 wich has the jsf impl built in.

The @ManagedProperty works only with an @ManagedBean I think and not with @Named. The problem I think you see is tha tboth Spring and JSF manage the component and you have actually multiple instances. Another issue is the viewscope itself as that will store the object in the session (serializing it) and deserializing it when needed. This will remove the field value. Looking at the Spring documentation JSF support is primarily for migration purposes now and not actively maintained. So I suspect you need to do additional work to make this work in newer JSF versions combined with CDI.

Thanks a lot! I followed the most upvoted answer from here and with the @Autowirable way (as shown in my question) it manages to get the adress of zService but initialising it (when it gets called) again, injects null. With the @Inject @ManagedProperty(EL) approach spring searches for my zService (recognizable from error logs) but cant find and inject it, although my zService works fine and can be injected in other spring beans

As I explained it doesn't autowire, as you have 2 instances. 1 spring managed and 1 JSF/CDI managed. The latter has nothing injected because it doesn't know anything about @Autowired. You pointed to an answer that does the injection itself in the @PostConstruct by using the FacesContextUtils to get the applicationcontext and wire the dependencies in. And from what I read on different sites @ManagedProperty doesn't actually work with CDI (as expected as it belongs to JSF not CDI).
